# Python : Difficulty finding direction from 1 point to another

Tags: python, math, simulation

I am trying to make a orbit simulator in Python and i have some basic mechanics like acceleration , velocity implemented.
I was trying to implement Newtonian gravitational formula `GMm/r**2`
But there to calculate the direction of the force im doing something like this 
`dir = Vec2(object.posX-object2.posX,object.posY-object2.posY)`
and then applying the `math.atan` function to convert the slope into angle
`dir_angle = math.atan(dir.y/dir.x)`
This is later used to calculate the X and Y direction component of force as acceleration

```
object2.acceleration_x = dt * f * math.sin(dir_angle)/object2.mass
object2.acceleration_y = dt * f * math.cos(dir_angle)/object2.mass
```

But value of `dir.x` and `dir.y` initially is `-100,100`
so atan is `-.78` but eventually , the `dirx` and `diry` become `1,-1`.
But the slope remains the same and the angle remains the same , not reversing the direction of force.
 How can i fix this so the force can change direction when I want.

Comment: Remember that `atan` only works for half the circle.  It can't tell the difference between `1/2` and `-1/-2`.  You should be using `math.atan2`.

Comment: @TimRoberts so here can i just swap atan2 for atan , or some conversions between functions are required?

Comment: atan2 takes two arguments

Comment: RIght.  Instead of `math.atan(y/x)`, you do `math.atan2(y,x)`.  `atan2` checks the sign of the two arguments before doing the division so it can correct the quadrant.